# ClickOnce publishing to CodePlex

Tags: clickonce, web-deployment, codeplex

When attempting to publish my project to CodePlex as a ClickOnce, following the instructions [here](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ClickOnce), I keep getting the following error:

> ```
> Connecting to 'http://sentinel.codeplex.com/releases/clickonce/'...
> Error: Failed to connect to 'http://sentinel.codeplex.com/releases/clickonce/' with the following error: Unable to create the Web site 'http://sentinel.codeplex.com/releases/clickonce'. The Web server does not appear to have FrontPage Server Extensions installed.
> Publish failed.
> ```

I'm using the Subversion source-control interface, at no point has Visual Studio asked for any credentials (although it is possible that AnkhSVN will supply them for me).

Am I missing something obvious?

I've tried from two machines, I've ensured version numbers and prerequisites are set appropriately but don't think that is contributing to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure your publishing file location points to the location the files go. I haven't published to CodePlex (yet) but is it FTP? If so, the publishing file location would be something like ftp://theaddressandfolder, and the installation URL would be something like http://thewebaddressandfolder/

Comment: Whilst not exactly the problem, reading the guide and your comment more carefully has allowed me to at least upload a clickOnce install to CodePlex, even if it is via the "Publish" wizard.